# added to statement and now it doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to find where the error is in a SQL statement, but can't seem to locate it. VBA is telling me "Compile error: Mehthod or data member not found" and highlights `[RotationalServings7]= '" & Me.Text499 & "'` but after looking at it over and over, it seems right to me. Also `debug.print mysql2` doesn't give me the shred out showing what it's executing.

side note; it worked just fine until I added all the 9 and 10 items. Looked through the form and all the information is correct, same with the table it's updating.

```
    mysql2 = "UPDATE Thaw_Tags_FTI SET [RotationalItem1]= '" & Me.Combo445.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat1]= '" & Me.Text449 & "',[RotationalSS1]= '" & Me.Text452 & "',[RotationalServings1]= '" & Me.Text447 & "',[RotationalItem2]= '" & Me.Combo455.Column(1) & "'," _
& "[RotationalMeat2]= '" & Me.Text459 & "',[RotationalSS2]= '" & Me.Text461 & "',[RotationalServings2]= '" & Me.Text457 & "',[RotationalItem3]= '" & Me.Combo463.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat3]= '" & Me.Text467 & "',[RotationalSS3]= '" & Me.Text469 & "'," _
& "[RotationalServings3]= '" & Me.Text465 & "',[RotationalItem4]= '" & Me.Combo471.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat4]= '" & Me.Text475 & "',[RotationalSS4]= '" & Me.Text477 & "',[RotationalServings4]= '" & Me.Text473 & "',[RotationalItem5]= '" & Me.Combo479.Column(1) & "'," _
& "[RotationalMeat5]= '" & Me.Text483 & "',[RotationalSS5]= '" & Me.Text486 & "',[RotationalServings5]= '" & Me.Text481 & "',[RotationalItem6]= '" & Me.Combo489.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat6]= '" & Me.Text493 & "',[RotationalSS6]= '" & Me.Text495 & "',[RotationalServings6]= '" & Me.Text491 & "'," _
& "[RotationalItem7]= '" & Me.Combo497.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat7]= '" & Me.Text501 & "',[RotationalSS7]= '" & Me.Text503 & "',[RotationalServings7]= '" & Me.Text499 & "',[RotationalItem8]= '" & Me.Combo505.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat8]= '" & Me.Text509 & "',[RotationalSS8]= '" & Me.Text511 & "',[RotationalServings8]= '" & Me.Text507 & "'," _
& "[RotationalItem9]= '" & Me.Combo778.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat9]= '" & Me.Text789 & "',[RotationalSS9]= '" & Me.Text784 & "',[RotationalServings9]= '" & Me.Text780 & "',[RotationalItem10]= '" & Me.Combo787.Column(1) & "',[RotationalMeat10]= '" & Me.Text791 & "',[RotationalSS10]= '" & Me.Text793 & "',[RotationalServings10]= '" & Me.Text789 & "'" _
& "WHERE [ID]=Forms!Thaw_Report_FTI!Combo160"
```

Comment: Need a space in front of the WHERE so string won't run together when it compiles. Or put the space after the last apostrophe within the quote marks. Also, concatentate the criteria: `" WHERE [ID]=" & Forms!Thaw_Report_FTI.Combo160`

Comment: You have added `" _& " add the end of each line that doesn't make any sense. Removing it should fix your error. Try to format SQL in some tools (https://sqlformat.org) to see this type of errors.

Comment: @mx0, the `_ &` are correct for constructing SQL string in VBA. The `_` is line continuation character and the `&` is string concatenation.

Comment: Remove new added line and then check your query after adding each element. You probably have typo in one of the `Me.Text*` elements.

Comment: Actually, the `Method or data member not found` could apply to any of the controls that he is referencing in that code because it is actually ONE single long line of code.  He is using line continuation characters, so any of those controls referenced as `Me.TextXXX` or `Me.ComboXXX`  could be invalid.  And, with such helpful and meaningful control names, I am sure this will be a breeze to determine ;-)

Comment: And, as @June7 points out, they haven't gotten to the point of being able to see if they are generating valid SQL yet.  There may be other issues in addition to the `WHERE` issue if some of those controls have Null values, or worse, if one of those Combo Boxes is a multi-value control, which IMO you should never use.

Comment: And as far as the references to comboboxes, usually you want the value in the combobox, not what is in the second column. Column index begins with 0 so reference to index 1 is the second column. If you want the value of the combobox, no need to reference column index.

Comment: The error you reported would happen if the form where you're building that string does not contain a control named `Text499`

Comment: @HansUp, that's what the issue was. I erased it all and started over, ended up being the one right before the error.

Comment: at everyone else, the reason I use column(1) and not (0) is because I am getting the name of an item from a query, not the number (which would be column 0). There is a method to my madness, if you see the form you'll understand. It's also easy for me to find the combo/text box based off of the field it's going into, so naming each box would just be additional work.